# Wie alt ist die Phrase »die Fäden ziehen«?

Tags: phrase

In English "to pull strings" (1823), und Ursprung von Marionetten-Theater.

Is it by any chance older (in this meaning) in German?

Comment: In Schillers "Kabale und Liebe" von 1784 kommt vor: 
*Ich halte dich an deiner eigenen Schurkerei, wie den Schröter* (wahrscheinlich ein Schneider)  *am Faden.* Kann Ähnliches bedeuten.

Comment: Der erste Satz soll was bedeuten?

Comment: @tofor: Ist [Schröter](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schr%C3%B6ter_%28Beruf%29) nicht jemand, der Fässer mit Hanfseilen bewegt, und kein Schneider? Obwohl dann immer noch unklar ist, wieso der Schröter selbst am Faden gehalten wird.

Comment: @dirkt DWD listet als eine der Bedeutungen von *Schröter* den "Schneider" - Der erschien mir am passendsten - Ein Puppenspieler war leider nicht dabei...

Answer (score 4):

Im Marionetten-Theater heißen die Fäden, an denen die Puppen hängen, auch »Drähte«, und im Norden Deutschlands auch »Strippen«. Daher stammt nicht nur die Redewendung »die Fäden ziehen« vom Marionettentheater, sondern auch:

- die Strippen ziehen
- Drahtzieher

Ich habe versucht, in einem [Ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=F%C3%A4den%20ziehen%2CStrippen%20ziehen%2CDrahtzieher&year_start=1750&year_end=2000&corpus=20&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2CF%C3%A4den%20ziehen%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2CStrippen%20ziehen%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2CDrahtzieher%3B%2Cc0) die historische Häufigkeit dieser Begriffe zu analysieren:

[image]
Aber wie man sieht: Sobald ein Begriff aus mehreren Wörtern besteht, die gebeugt sein können, und deren Reihenfolge nicht fix ist, kommt man mit einem Ngram leider nicht weit. Vor allen kann mit »Faden ziehen« auch die Tätigkeit eines Chirurgen oder eines Schneiders gemeint sein.

Die Wortfolge »Fäden ziehen« tauchte jedenfalls in Druckwerken schon um 1760 auf, und war um 1810 relativ populär. Diese Wortfolge wurde jedenfalls in den Büchern, die Google eingescannt hat, rund um 1810 häufiger verwendet als heute.

Beim Drahtzieher ist es leichter: Den gibt es offenbar seit ca. 1763, richtig populär wurde er aber erst ab ca. 1920.